# How to create an JDBC SQL view with graphdb REST API in python

Tags: rest, sparql, graph-databases, graphdb

I am working with GraphDB on a knowledge graph and would like to dynamically generate JDBC SQL views using the REST API :

https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/10.0/devhub/rest-api/curl-commands.html?%20api#repository-management

http://graph.openbiodiv.net/webapi

It works fine for the get functions (get the SQL view configuration of the active repository, [get the names of all the views in the active repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmVV0.png))
for example:

```
import requests
x = requests.get('http://localhost:7200/rest/sql-views/tables')
```

But when I am now trying to create a new view with the following code:

(viewrqst is really just an example to make sure it works, before using my actual query)

```
viewrqst="SELECT ?s WHERE {?s ?p ?m1. ?m1 ?pp ?s2. #!filter}"

viewbody={
'name': 'viewpython',
"query": viewrqst,
"columns":[
{
"column_name":"s1",
"column_type":"string",
"nullable":True,
"sparql_type":"string",
"sql_type_precision":0,
"sql_type_scale":0
}
]
}

r = requests.post('http://localhost:7200/rest/sql-views/tables/',json=viewbody)
print(r.text)
```

I get the following error

```
{"message":"Syntax error in query:  (Encountered \"<EOF>\" at line 2, column 50.\r\nWas expecting one of:\r\n    \"{\" ...\r\n    \"}\" ...\r\n    \"optional\" ...\r\n    \"graph\" ...\r\n    \"minus\" ...\r\n    \"filter\" ...\r\n    \"bind\" ...\r\n    \"service\" ...\r\n    \"values\" ...\r\n    )."}
```

It may be because of the #!filter but without it, I get the following error

```
{"message":"Invalid SQL View:  (No specified !filter optimization clause)."}
```

I tried doing the same thing directly from GraphDB REST API page which is directly connected to my database and allows to test the methods (http://graph.openbiodiv.net/webapi) but I get similar problems.

[the body of the post resquest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98v6q.png)

[the response, with 400 code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KKtx.png)

Does anyone know how to write the body of the request? Or what could cause the eof error? Is the # comment actually being considered as a comment or as part of the code ?

EDIT: someone suggested the problem may come from the use of 's1' which doesn't appear anywhere else, I thought column_name could be chosen arbitrarily but here are some other examples to make sure :

[request and response on graphdb api page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPgB9.png)

[request and response with python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4L7R.png)

Thank you for your help

Comment: Unrelated, but are you sure your JSON is correct? You define a `column_name`  with `s1` which doesn't occur anywhere in the SPARQL query.

Comment: I thought column_name was unrelated to any other occurrence and could be chosen arbitrarily, thats why.

I just changed it and put s instead but I still have the same problem. Thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using devtools on GraphDDB and looking at the network activity while creating an sql view I found out I was missing  \n before and after the #!filter
so at the end I'd have  WHERE{ ... \n #!filter \n }

and as it was mentioned to me by someone it is in fact important to keep the same name in column_name and in the query.